# GraphicsMagick, Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: undefined-symbol, graphicsmagick

I am trying to install GraphicsMagick in Xcode4, I am getting this error when i execute command 'make'.

```
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: magick/.libs/libGraphicsMagick.a(magick_libGraphicsMagick_la-module.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: magick/.libs/libGraphicsMagick.a(magick_libGraphicsMagick_la-PreRvIcccm.o) has no symbols
libtool: link: ranlib magick/.libs/libGraphicsMagick.a
ranlib: file: magick/.libs/libGraphicsMagick.a(magick_libGraphicsMagick_la-module.o) has no symbols
ranlib: file: magick/.libs/libGraphicsMagick.a(magick_libGraphicsMagick_la-PreRvIcccm.o) has no symbols


Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___builtin_object_size", referenced from:
      _BlurImageScanlines.omp_fn.6 in libGraphicsMagick.a(magick_libGraphicsMagick_la-effect.o)
      _XShearImage.omp_fn.0 in libGraphicsMagick.a(magick_libGraphicsMagick_la-shear.o)
      _YShearImage.omp_fn.1 in libGraphicsMagick.a(magick_libGraphicsMagick_la-shear.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [utilities/gm] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a solution here.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmagick/forums/forum/250738/topic/5221775

Answer (score 2):

GraphicsMagick won't compile on OS X 10.7 (Lion) or 10.8 (Mountain Lion) with the default LLVM GCC/G++ compilers. The workaround is to use the Clang compiler instead:

```
./configure CC=clang [...other config options...]
```

It is also a good idea to run the unit tests with `make check` after compilation just to be on the safe side.

This trick worked for me, hope it helps.